# Error: spawn EACCES -- Derivados debian -- ionic

Tags: nodejs, linux, cordova, debian, ionic-framework

Hola que tal amigos tengo un problema con ionic al momento de correr una app creada.
Al momento de tipear el comando "ionic serve" me vota este resultado y la verdad es raro porque encuentro soluciones al error pero nada comparado con el mio ya que inicia y va todo bien hasta que sale este error "Error: spawn EACCES " y la verdad no tengo ni la menor idea de lo que ocurre...

Vista:

```
usuario@usuario:~/ionic/MyApp# ionic serve
  [INFO] Starting server (address: 0.0.0.0, port: 8100, livereload port: 35729) -  Ctrl+C to cancel

  [INFO] Development server running
  Local: http://localhost:8100
  External: http://10.76.0.200:8100

  Error: spawn EACCES
usuario@usuario:~/ionic/MyApp#
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 No tengo idea de como solucionarlo vale Gracias...

He agregado permisos y nada como podeis ver aqui...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: EACCES: `The requested access would be denied to the file, or search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of pathname`. error al intentar leer/ejecutar un programa/*script*: permisos incorrectos, directorio inexistente, permisos de directorio incorrectos, ... Comprueba que tu usuario tiene acceso para todo lo que uses.

Comment: He agregado permisos y nada

Comment: Si fuera yo, usaria `strace` y/o `ltrace` para identificar el problema real ... échales un ojo. Sirven para trazar las llamadas al `kernel` y las llamadas reales a la libreria `libc`. O espera, a ver si algún usuario con experiencia en `ionic` te puede ayudar.

Comment: Soy un poco nuevo con respecto a los errores por consola...

Comment: Disculpa la incomodidad pero no se como hacer eso.

Comment: Intenta `strace -q -e execve -f -o strace.txt ionic serve`. Te generará un archivo `strace.txt`, mas o menos grande. Dentro, habrá líneas del tipo `execve("/usr/bin/ionic", ...' . Cada una de esas líneas te indica que archivo estas intentando ejecutar. Una de las últimas líneas que aparezcan contendrá el que te está fallando. Hay que comprobar *a mano* las rutas, los permisos, ...

Comment: Me dice esto bash: strace: no se encontró la orden